# How to use logistic operator JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="image">
<img id="img-1" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
<img id="img-2" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
<img id="img-5" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
<img id="img-15" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
<img id="img-25" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
<img id="img-35" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
<img id="img-50" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
</div>

 $(".image img").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            getClass = $this.attr('img')
        splitClass = $this.prop('id').split("-")
        if (splitClass[1] <= 20) {
            $this.attr("src", "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1");
            this.nextElementSibling.remove();

        } else if (splitClass[1] >= 21) {
            $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");
            this.nextElementSibling.remove();

        } else {
            $this.attr("src", "https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif");
        }
    });
```

How does > , < , <= , >= work in jQuery ?
the default img is default-avatar.gif.
i want `(splitClass[1] >= 21)` the img change with min is 21 and the max is 40.
and then the....

```
else {
        $this.attr("src", "https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif");
            }
```

will work with default-avatar.gif because i dont change it in jQuery.

Comment: Operators are nothing to do with jQuery. If you have value '23' then you need to parseInt('23') and work as number and you can apply the operators. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: What is expected result of `getClass = $this.attr('img')`?

Comment: @guest271314 really? I thought javascript is not dynamic typeing language and you always need convert string to the number for operators.

Comment: Wowzers! JavaScript has *logistic operators* now? These babel folks know how to please mathematicians.

Comment: @daremachine Try at `console` `"19" < 20` , `"21" < 20` , `51 > "57"`

Comment: @guest271314 thank you for extend my knowledge but its working only for <>= not for all like a +/- ... I still thinking its ugly mixed string and number for compare. IMHO

Comment: @daremachine `"4" - 3` , `+"3" + 4`, `-3 + +"-4"`

Comment: @guest271314 yea but "4" + 3 does mistake as well. Still not professional approach for me =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `.hide()` for `.remove()` within `.each()` loop. You can also add a `className` to the elements where `display:none` is set at `css` to select and remove the elements from `document` after iteration at `.each()`.

```js
$(".image img").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    getClass = $this.attr('img')
  splitClass = $this.prop('id').split("-")
  if (splitClass[1] <= 20) {
    $this.attr("src", "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1");
    $this.next().hide(); // .addClass("toRemove")
    console.log("less than or equal to 20", splitClass[1] <= 20)
  } else if (splitClass[1] >= 21) {
    $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");
    $this.next().hide(); // .addClass("toRemove")
    console.log("greater than or equal to 20", splitClass[1] >= 21)
  } else {
    $this.attr("src", "https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif");
  }
}); // .filter(".toRemove").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">
  <img id="img-1" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
  <img id="img-2" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
  <img id="img-5" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
  <img id="img-15" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
  <img id="img-25" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
  <img id="img-35" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
  <img id="img-50" src="https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/images/verge/default-avatar.v9899025.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: @KarlFriedchicken Note, `img` elements do not appear to have attribute named `img`; what is purpose of `getClass = $this.attr('img')`?